# Expressjs app.render isn't working

Tags: node.js, express, haml

When I call

```
app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    res.render('index', {locals: {title: 'Hello, Node!' }});
});
```

it outputs

```
TypeError: Object "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n" +
"<html>" + 
"</html>" +
"<title>" + 
title + 
"</title>" +
"<body>" + 
"</body>" +
"<s>" + 
"Hello, World" + 
"</s>" has no method 'call'
    at ServerResponse._render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.2.2/package/lib/view.js:377:21)
    at ServerResponse.render (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/2.2.2/package/lib/view.js:242:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/william/www/html_public/app.js:36:6)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/middleware/router.js:148:21)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/middleware/router.js:164:10)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/middleware/router.js:170:6)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:76:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.3.0/package/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
```

This is my express configuration

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.set('view engine', 'haml');
    app.set("view options", { layout: false });

    // Set directorys
    app.use(express.static(public_dir));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
});
```

How do I fix this whats wrong. It seems to be calling a function which doesnt exists??

---

This is the haml code

```
!!!
%html
    %title= title

%body
    %s Hello, World
```

**Fixed!!**
This configure fixes the compatibly with the haml libary

```
var haml = require('haml');

app.register('.haml', {
    compile: function(str, options) {
        return function(locals) {
            return haml.render(str, {locals: locals});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also which version of express / node are you using? Try upgrading to the latest stable ones.

```
// render
var str = view.fn.call(options.scope, options);
```

That's what renders your view.

```
view.fn = engine.compile(view.contents, options)
```

That's what creates the function. `.compile` is defined in your haml engine. My guess it's a bug in the haml engine as that's a non standard engine.

[haml](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js) is not compliant with express out of the box. All express view engines are expected to have a `.compile` function which returns a function that can be called to return html. the `.compile` method in `haml` does not return what express expects.

try [haml-js](https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js/tree/) which was written by the express guys and is maintained by the express guys.

Alternatively if you read the docs for [app.register](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.register%28%29) it shows you how to turn any view engine into an express compatible view engine.

Comment: No I am using haml, that's the compiled html

Comment: @Will03uk you could have mentioned that. No need for the downvote.

Comment: Im using node v0.4.5 and express v2.2.2

Comment: @will03uk what's your haml view engine?